# list all sites I can access

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Is it possible to list all site collections (or groups) I have access (owner or member) to with PnP PowerShell? I tried to connect to the `tenant.sharepoint.com` or `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites` but after that the get-* commands fail with `unauthorized` error message.
Is there a solution to do this? Sometimes users are completely lost and Would be great just to pass a script to the users, and say, this will list all your sites.

Comment: Check [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-SharePoint-Online-and-7e6afce2), let me know if it helps you.

Comment: This is about subsites under a site collection

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the below CSOM PowerShell script where you need to pass the **Site URL**, Particular User Name(**UserAccount**), and **ReportFile** as parameters - this will scan through the all permission details for the given users across the site objects for the given site.

**Parameters to pass:**

```
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Ops"
$UserAccount="i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.com"
$ReportFile="C:\Temp\PermissionRpt.csv"
```

**PowerShell script to get a particular user permission report:**

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
  
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Ops"
$UserAccount="i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.com"
$ReportFile="C:\Temp\PermissionRpt.csv"

#To call a non-generic method Load
Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {
    param(
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject]$Object = $(throw "Please provide a Client Object"),
            [string]$PropertyName
        )
   $ctx = $Object.Context
   $load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load")
   $type = $Object.GetType()
   $clientLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type)
  
   $Parameter = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter(($type), $type.Name)
   $Expression = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Convert([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::PropertyOrField($Parameter,$PropertyName),[System.Object] ), $($Parameter))
   $ExpressionArray = [System.Array]::CreateInstance($Expression.GetType(), 1)
   $ExpressionArray.SetValue($Expression, 0)
   $clientLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($Object,$ExpressionArray))
}

#Get Permissions Applied on a particular Object, such as: Web, List, Folder or Item
Function Get-Permissions([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SecurableObject]$Object)
{
    #Determine the type of the object
    Switch($Object.TypedObject.ToString())
    {
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web"  { $ObjectType = "Site" ; $ObjectURL = $Object.URL }
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem"
        {
            $ObjectType = "List Item/Folder"

            #Get the URL of the List Item
            Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $Object.ParentList -PropertyName "DefaultDisplayFormUrl"
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            $DefaultDisplayFormUrl = $Object.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl
            $ObjectURL = $("{0}{1}?ID={2}" -f $Ctx.Web.Url.Replace($Ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl,''), $DefaultDisplayFormUrl,$Object.ID)
        }
        Default
        {
            $ObjectType = "List/Library"
            #Get the URL of the List or Library
            $Ctx.Load($Object.RootFolder)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()           
            $ObjectURL = $("{0}{1}" -f $Ctx.Web.Url.Replace($Ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl,''), $Object.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)
        }
    }

    #Get permissions assigned to the object
    $Ctx.Load($Object.RoleAssignments)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Foreach($RoleAssignment in $Object.RoleAssignments)
    {
                $Ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
                $Ctx.executeQuery()

                #Check direct permissions
                if($RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq "User")
                {
                    #Is the current user is the user we search for?
                    if($RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $SearchUser.LoginName)
                    {
                        Write-Host  -f Cyan "Found the User under direct permissions of the $($ObjectType) at $($ObjectURL)"
                         
                        #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                        $UserPermissions=@()
                        $Ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                        foreach ($RoleDefinition in $RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                        {
                            $UserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                        }
                        #Send the Data to Report file
                        "$($ObjectURL) `t $($ObjectType) `t $($Object.Title)`t Direct Permission `t $($UserPermissions)" | Out-File $ReportFile -Append
                    }
                }
                 
                Elseif($RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq "SharePointGroup")
                {
                        #Search inside SharePoint Groups and check if the user is member of that group
                        $Group= $Web.SiteGroups.GetByName($RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName)
                        $GroupUsers=$Group.Users
                        $Ctx.Load($GroupUsers)
                        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                        #Check if user is member of the group
                        Foreach($User in $GroupUsers)
                        {
                            #Check if the search users is member of the group
                            if($user.LoginName -eq $SearchUser.LoginName)
                            {
                                Write-Host -f Cyan "Found the User under Member of the Group '"$RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName"' on $($ObjectType) at $($ObjectURL)"

                                #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                $GroupPermissions=@()
                                $Ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                                Foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                {
                                    $GroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                }         
                                #Send the Data to Report file
                                "$($ObjectURL) `t $($ObjectType) `t $($Object.Title)`t Member of '$($RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName)' Group `t $($GroupPermissions)" | Out-File $ReportFile -Append
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
}

Try {
        #Get Credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
  
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

        #Get the Web
        $Web = $Ctx.Web
        $Ctx.Load($Web)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get the User object
        $SearchUser = $Web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
        $Ctx.Load($SearchUser)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Write CSV- TAB Separated File) Header
        "URL `t Object `t Title `t PermissionType `t Permissions" | out-file $ReportFile

        Write-host -f Yellow "Searching in the Site Collection Administrators Group..."
        #Check if Site Collection Admin
        If($SearchUser.IsSiteAdmin -eq $True)
        {
            Write-host -f Cyan "Found the User under Site Collection Administrators Group!"
            #Send the Data to report file
           "$($Web.URL) `t Site Collection `t $($Web.Title)`t Site Collection Administrator `t Site Collection Administrator" | Out-File $ReportFile -Append
         }

        #Function to Check Permissions of All List Items of a given List
        Function Check-SPOListItemsPermission([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$List)
        {
            Write-host -f Yellow "Searching in List Items of the List '"$List.Title "'..."
            $ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
            $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            foreach($ListItem in $ListItems)
            {
                Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $ListItem -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
                $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                if ($ListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)
                {
                    #Call the function to generate Permission report
                    Get-Permissions -Object $ListItem
                }
            }
        }

        #Function to Check Permissions of all lists from the web
        Function Check-SPOListPermission([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web)
        {
            #Get All Lists from the web
            $Lists = $Web.Lists
            $Ctx.Load($Lists)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #Get all lists from the web  
            ForEach($List in $Lists)
            {
                #Exclude System Lists
                If($List.Hidden -eq $False)
                {
                    #Get List Items Permissions
                    Check-SPOListItemsPermission $List

                    #Get the Lists with Unique permission
                    Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $List -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
                    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                    If( $List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
                    {
                        #Call the function to check permissions
                        Get-Permissions -Object $List
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #Function to Check Webs's Permissions from given URL
        Function Check-SPOWebPermission([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web)
        {
            #Get all immediate subsites of the site
            $Ctx.Load($web.Webs) 
            $Ctx.executeQuery()
  
            #Call the function to Get Lists of the web
            Write-host -f Yellow "Searching in the Web "$Web.URL"..."

            #Check if the Web has unique permissions
            Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $Web -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            #Get the Web's Permissions
            If($web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)
            {
                Get-Permissions -Object $Web
            }

            #Scan Lists with Unique Permissions
            Write-host -f Yellow "Searching in the Lists and Libraries of "$Web.URL"..."
            Check-SPOListPermission($Web)
  
            #Iterate through each subsite in the current web
            Foreach ($Subweb in $web.Webs)
            {
                    #Call the function recursively                           
                    Check-SPOWebPermission($SubWeb)
            }
        }

        #Call the function with RootWeb to get site collection permissions
        Check-SPOWebPermission $Web

        Write-host -f Green "User Permission Report Generated Successfully!"
     }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Generating User Permission Report!" $_.Exception.Message
   }
```

**Demo output:**

[image: SharePoint-Online-Permission-Report-for-Specific-User-in-a-Site-Collection-using-PowerShell]

Source - Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Permission Report for Specific User in a Site Collection using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-online-permission-report-specific-user-site-collection-using-powershell/)

**Note**:

The function will list out permission report from a given site, so order to get the permission report from the tenant - you could call the above function inside the **foreach** loop of **Get-SPOSite** collection, example as below:

```
#Load SharePoint Online Assemblies

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
  
#Variables for Processing
$AdminUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$UserName= "username@tenant.com"
$Password = "Password goes here"
  
#Setup Credentials to connect
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $SecurePassword
 
#connect to the service
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminUrl -Credential $Credentials
 
#sharepoint online get all site collections PowerShell
$SiteColl = Get-SPOSite
 
#sharepoint online PowerShell iterate through all site collections
ForEach($Site in $SiteColl)
{
    Write-host $Site.Url
}
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Get All Site Collections using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/get-all-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html#:%7E:text=PowerShell%20to%20Get%20All%20Site%20Collections%20in%20SharePoint%20Online%3A,site%20collections%20in%20the%20tenant.)

Comment: Updated my post. I need to enumerate all site collections (sorry if site was misleading), not the subites under a site collections.

Comment: Get-SPOSite - will list out all site collection not subsite, inside the loop of Get-SPOSite collection, you could call the above permission report function.

Comment: I know. But in my post I also say that I need to solve this with PnP, as end users should be able to run this.

Comment: Until end user has admin right or share the admin user details they cannot connect to SharePoint tenant either through powershell or PnP

Comment: Ok, so connecting to a single site collection works for a normal user (we tested this), but no way to loop trough site collections?

Comment: Yes, connecting to single site collection would be possible if that user is part owner group but to loop through all site collection in tenant that user must at least SharePoint administrator or global administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use search api to get site you can access:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'
```

Comment: Updated my post. I need to enumerate all site collections (sorry if site was misleading), not the subites under a site collections.